# Get a reference to a string-array outside Main Activity

Tags: java, android, arrays

I've made a `string-array` to hold some phrases which should be displayed each time I call a method of a `class`, the `Master` class.

But when I type `Resources res = getResources();`

It marks that `getResources()` in red saying there's no such method.

Instead if I type it into the Main Activity everything looks good.

**How** can I **get** a `reference` to a `string-array` **outside** the `Main` so I can create that `method` **inside** my `Master` Class?

This is my string-array:

```
<string-array name="goodMorning">
    <item>Good Morning folks!</item>
      [...]
    <item>Be beep. Be beep. %s wake up!</item>
</string-array>
```

**EDIT:**

This is my Master class now

```
public class Master extends Player {
private String mName;
private Context context;


public String getmName(){
    return mName;
} // Get Master's name

public static int randInt(int min, int max) { //Get a random int between two values

    // Usually this can be a field rather than a method variable
    Random rand = new Random();

    // nextInt is normally exclusive of the top value,
    // so add 1 to make it inclusive
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

    return randomNum;
}


public Master(Context c){ //it's your contsructor method
    this.context = c;
}


public void goodMorning() { // Get a random phrase from a String-Array and display it to the user
    int randomNumber = randInt(0, 8); //Random Number
    String[] arrayPhrases = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.goodMorning); // String-Array with 'morning phrases
    List<String> listPhrases = new ArrayList<>(); // List

    Collections.addAll(listPhrases, arrayPhrases); // Insert the String-Array in the List
    String randomPhrase = listPhrases.get(randomNumber); // Get the random phrase

    System.out.printf(randomPhrase); // Display it
}
}
```

And this is my Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Master m = new Master(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

m.goodMorning();

}
```

The **problem** is that when I call `m.goodMorning();` it doesn't recognize the goodMorning() method, any ideas?

Comment: you need to pass a context to that method

Comment: Or, pass the `String[]` to that method. "Instead if I type it into the Main Activity everything looks good" -- that is because `getResources()` is a method on `Context`, and `Activity` inherits from `Context`.

Comment: If you want help with the code, please show where and how the Master object is instantiate, and the Master class codes.

Comment: please add some more code to be specific on your question

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with that way.

Your **MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity()
{
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContextView(R.layout.yourlayout);
           /*
                 Your operations 
           */

     }
     private void createClass()
     {
          YourMaster yourMaster = new YourMaster(MainActivity.this);
          yourMaster.doSomething();
     }

}
```

**YourMaster.Class**

```
public class YourMaster
{
     private Context context;
     YourMaster(Context _context)    //it's your contsructor methot
     {
          this.context = _context;
     }
     private void doSomething()
     {
          context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.goodMorning);

          //your array is yours now.
     }

}
```